# VS Code is not accepting Optional Chaining operator in Node.js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, optional-chaining

I'm using Node.js 14.15.1 in VS Code and it is showing an error when I'm trying to use the optional chaining operator. I am not using any other dependency apart from Express. The line of code is fairly simple.

```
if(something.includes(String(anotherThing.value)?.trim())) {
 // do something
}
```

Can you shed some light on a possible workaround?

Comment: According to [node.green](https://node.green/) this feature should be available in NodeJs 14.5. Can Node run this code?

Comment: @PaulMartin That's a typo in the question. The code has it.

Comment: VSC remote uses a different V8 version

Comment: Did you update your `jsconfig.json` `target` and `lib` properties to something like `es2020`?